# Multiplication In MASM611

Tags: masm, multiplication

hii i have a problem in multiplication for above 5 bits i'm working in MASM611 plz tell me the solution which is for atleast 8 bit multiplication in MASM611

Comment: Please post the code you already have, so we can start from there.

Answer (score 0):

for unsigned integer multiply, use mul; for signed use imul. if the operand is an 8-bit register, you get a 16-bit result.

for example:

```
mov al, 3
mov cl, 5
mul cl
```

puts 15 in ax.

study this page: http://web.archive.org/web/20120414214754/http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_6/CH06-2.html

Comment: if that's not what you wanted, please be more specific; OK?

Comment: al cannot hold a value greater than 8 bits=255, 0xff

Comment: @user512770: do you understand now?

Comment: i want to multiply 8 digit multiplication in MASM but after the when i go for above 4 digit teh resuls are going poor and poor so plz help me that how i can make this possible so that i get the good results....

Comment: 4 digit numbers are more than 8 bits. for 16-bit multiplication:

Comment: mov ax, 1000; mov cx, 5; mul cx; answer will be in ax (actually dx:ax, but dx should be empty since the answer fits in 16 bits)

Comment: I added a link to my answer that should help.

Comment: yes plz tell me that i want to multiply the 8 digitd numbers plz help me out

Comment: just try this for mov eax,10000000

Comment: sir is there any way for mov ebx,1000000 mov eax,10 mul eax

Comment: if you mul eax by ebx, your answer will be in edx:eax, the most significant bits in edx. the link is in the answer I edited above.

Comment: but you have to write mul ebx, not mul eax, because eax is assumed to be the first operand.

Comment: Replacement for the book link above that has gone 404: http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH06/CH06-2.html

Comment: thanks for the heads up! I figure the archive.org backup is less likely to change, so used that instead.